# Python Code Loop Multiple Times

Tags: python

I m trying to repeat the code multiple times.But it is not working properly.I used this code for code repetition below.With this code i want to open website and click the button and want to loop ten times.What is problem in my code?

```
count = 0       
while count < 10        
browser.get('http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/create/')       
time.sleep(8)       
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".formButtonMain.saveButton").click()    
time.sleep(8)       
count = count + 1
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what is the error and stack trace? Is your code running, but producing unexpected output? If so, what output are you getting, and what output did you expect to get?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a : after the while-line and forgot to [indent your code](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) afterwards.

```
count = 0       
while count < 10:        
    browser.get('http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/create/')       
    time.sleep(8)       
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".formButtonMain.saveButton").click()    
    time.sleep(8)       
    count = count + 1
```

A for loop would probably fit better though, this way you can get rid of the count variable.

```
for i in range(10):        
    browser.get('http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/create/')       
    time.sleep(8)       
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".formButtonMain.saveButton").click()    
    time.sleep(8)
```